# Android: right align TextView and no truncate

Tags: android, textview, truncate

I'm trying to align my `android:id="@+id/date"` TextView with the right side of the screen. This works, but the problem is when the TextView `android:id="@+id/name"` is long the date gets truncated. E.g. instead of "Mon 1/26" it will read "Mon 1...". How can I fix this so the full date is always shown? Below is my xml file. Thank you in advance for the help!

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/instance_chart"
    style="@style/InstanceChart"
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.my.name.chart.ChartView
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:id="@+id/chart_view"
        app:barLabelHeight="0sp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        style="@style/InstanceChart.Chart" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    style="@style/InstanceChart.Title"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/symbol"
        android:layout_width="70sp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="left"

        style="@style/InstanceChart.Symbol"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"

        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"

        style="@style/InstanceChart.Name"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        />

</LinearLayout>    
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix... the last `textView` should be

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead. I assumed your want a 3 text column layout, with second one stretched as much as possible.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    style="@style/InstanceChart.Title"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/symbol"
        android:layout_width="70sp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="left"

        style="@style/InstanceChart.Symbol"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"

        style="@style/InstanceChart.Name"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

When using `TextView`, `android:gravity` sets text alignment. However, `android:layout_gravity` sets `TextView`'s gravity in its container.

Here you are using a horizontal `LinearLayout` so you cannot apply horizontal alignment to all its children. For instance, set `android:layout_gravity="left"` on a `TextView` will not work.

Comment: Okay thanks. I've updated the code accordingly, but this does not solve my issue with truncating the date...

Comment: Try to remove `ellipsize` and `singleLine` attributes from 3rd `TextView`